# String comparison in Bash script not working

Tags: string, bash

I wrote the following script in Bash but it is not printing the desired output:

```
a="abc"

if (test "$a"="$a ") then 
    echo "true "
else
    echo "false "
fi
```

This script should print `false` but it isn't. I'm new to Bash scripting, so can anyone please tell me why it is not printing `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're giving `test` only one argument: `"$a"="$a "`, which is equivalent to `"$a=$a "`. When `test` gets only one argument, it evaluates to `0`/true/success if that argument contains at least one character, and to `1`/false/error otherwise. The minimal fix would be to put spaces around the `=`, so you're giving it three separate arguments:

```
if (test "$a" = "$a ") then
```

but I'd really recommend writing it in a Bashier style:

```
if [[ "$a" = "$a " ]] then
```

(Note that the `(` and `)` in the original version merely cause `test` to be run in a subshell, which really serves no purpose at all.)